# Nested ng-repeat for multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am trying to **display a bi-dimensional array in html using the ng-repeat directive**. I can display the first dimension ( table rows) but the second (table datas) is not working. I have seen a lot of solutions using objects, JSON, key-values data structures... But I can't find something that work **for just an array containing others arrays**. Here are some unsuccessful attempts.
**HTML:** (does't work)

```
<div ng-app = "grid" ng-controller = "gridCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "y in grid">
            <td ng-repeat = "x in y"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**HTML:** (doesn't work)

```
<div ng-app = "grid" ng-controller = "gridCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat = "y in grid">
            <td ng-repeat = "x in grid[$index]"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var grid = angular.module("grid", []);
grid.controller("gridCtrl", function($scope)
{
    $scope.grid = [[empty, empty, empty, empty, empty],
                   [empty, empty, empty, empty, empty],
                   [empty, empty, empty, empty, empty],
                   [empty, empty, empty, empty, empty],
                   [empty, empty, empty, empty, empty]];
});
```

Comment: The first try of yours seems fine. Can you add some jsFiddle code?

Comment: both methods [work fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/soiWMahMfEF8DnMkL2Ic?p=preview). Any console errors? do you have more than one `ng-app` perhaps? Show more code and update demo to reproduce problem

Comment: @charlietfl They work because you have differents values in the array, my code don't work because of the value repetition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working example:

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="y in grid">
        <td ng-repeat="x in y track by $index">{{x}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.grid = [["empty", "empty", "empt", "empt", "empty"],
                  ["empty", "empty", "empt", "empt", "empty"]];
});
```

demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yVC5nrH5Pv3Zzp8Py7FH?p=preview

As your array data contains duplicate you want to add `track by` for unique id so i had added `track by $index` more about this https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes

Comment: So if I understand my code wasn't working because it contained only one value, and 'track by' fix this?

Comment: `track by` is added only because the array data which you are given containes same value, if your array data has different values you code will work.

Comment: Please dont use nested ng-repeat
Try to make the object that ways.

Comment: this helped me a lot

Comment: If need use ng-model on td component need use y[$index] instead of x.
 <td ng-repeat="x in y track by $index"><input ng-model="y[$index]" type="text"></input></td>