# Angular ng-repeat on weekly basis

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to iterate the objects on Weekly basis. Lets Say there are 31 days, and i need to show those 31 dates on weekly basis. I tried by using `limitTo: 7`, but unfortunately it is not working. Below the code which i tried.

I want the same `div` having class `class="accordian-section"` needs to be repeat on every 7 objects. i.e. 1st 7 is in 1 `<div>`. And for the next 7 object the same needs to be repeat.

```
<div class="accordian-section" data-ng-repeat="data in vm.dailyUsageList track by $index | limitTo: 7:7">
     <a id="analysisWeek1-title" href="#analysisWeek-1" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" area-controls="analysisWeek-1">Week 1 <span class=""></span></a>
     <ul id="analysisWeek-1" area-labelledby="analysisWeek1-title" class="row position-relative panel-collapse collapse">
        <span class="sprite arrow grey-arrow"></span>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
        <li><span class="col-xs-14 padding0">{{data.date | date:'dd MMM yyyy'}}</span><span class="col-xs-2 padding0 text-align-right">{{data.usage}}MB</span></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: You should construct a data structure that represents the data you wish to display. e.g. you could have an array of arrays where the inner arrays is the data split into the days of the week for that month. You can then iterate over the arrays to display your data

Comment: Can I have a small peice of code, so that i will get some idea to do the Stuff? @Magrangs

Comment: Try a multidimensional array 5*7 span and have two ng-repeat.  controller is responsible for preparing data which the view can render, not that the view takes that responsibility to itself.  Such transformation is easily performed on the controller.

Try this [SO Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678928/nested-ng-repeat-for-multidimensional-array) for a simple way to transform data as an multi dimensional array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert single dimensional array into multi dimensional array. and Iterate [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10883/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.ArraySplit = function(array, chunk) {
            var temparray = [];
            for (i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
                temparray.push(array.slice(i, i + chunk));
            }
            return temparray;
        }


        $scope.arrayList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                            11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                            21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];

        $scope.newList = $scope.ArraySplit($scope.arrayList, 7)


    }
```